# How do I let tee print all file descriptors to screen but only save stdout to file?

Tags: tee

Suppose my program prints to multiple file descriptors and I need to watch all of the outputs as they are being printed but only save `stdout` to a file. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose 3 is one of those file descriptors you're interested in.
3 may be pointing to `file`, for example:

```
exec 3>file
```

Your app writes to 3:

```
app() { echo hello world >&3; }
```

If you want to interecept 3, you need to `dup` it to another file descriptor (e.g., 4):

```
exec 4>&3
```

and redirect (=replace) 3 with a pipe to your interceptor process, which has to write back to the original target (or else it wouldn't be an interceptor), which is now saved in fd 4:

```
app 3> >(tee /dev/tty >&4) #this interceptor writes to the terminal
```

The above should print `hello world` to the terminal and `file` should end up with `hello world` as well.

All this assume these filedescriptors are open before you start the process. If you want to intercept filedescriptor outputs dynamically at runtime, then I'm afraid you have to modify the code, inject code at runtime, or intercept system calls with something like `ptrace`.